# SQL variable missing quotations

Tags: python, sql, variables, quotes

I am working with a database and in column_x some variables were NULL. As someone did not prefer this we decided to change this to 'None'. Now I used the following command to change that in Python:

```
 query = "update stone set results = 'None' where results is null;"
```

But when I do:

```
 query = "SELECT * FROM stone where part = 'ABC';"
```

I get an output 'x','y','z',None,'a'

But when I do:

```
 query = "SELECT * FROM stone where part = 'ABC' and results = 'None';"
```

I get () returned. This is probably because 'None' does not exists. Thus short question long, how do I change None -> 'None' via Python?

Comment: Is this going to *always* be your pattern ('ABC' and 'None')? Using parameters would help resolve this if not. Also, make sure you're properly escaping the string 'None'. Finally, you may want to run this query directly on the database to see if there truly *is* a result set that falls within your search condition.

Comment: Yes sorry I might have not been clear there. I look for stone 'ABC' and I find it if I leave results empty. The value of results for stone 'ABC' = None   However when I search for 'ABC' and 'None' I do not get a result back. I think this is because None != 'None'

Comment: Am I missing something? My understanding is a NULL (absence of any value) is fixed by the database vendor. How can you look for None if NULL is returned, unless these are string variables, and you're writing in None or NULL. Is this the case?

Comment: The database contained for results the options  'Available','None',NULL now we changed NULL to 'None' (we thought) however now we have 'Available,'None',None and we cannot change None to 'None' whatever we try...

Comment: What's the table definition for `stone` (`describe stone;`)?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if when you said None you meant null.
If you intended None to mean null you can use something like this (MYSQL):

sql = "UPDATE stone set results=\'None\' where results is null"
cursor = conn.Execute($sql)
rows = cursor.Affected_Rows()

For Oracle, execute this SQL:

sql = "UPDATE stone set results=''None'' where results='None'"
cursor = conn.Execute($sql)
rows = cursor.Affected_Rows()

For MYSQL, you need to use a backslash to escape the tick - something like

sql = "UPDATE stone set results=\'None\' where results='None'"
cursor = conn.Execute($sql)
rows = cursor.Affected_Rows()

See also
http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/adodb-py-docs.htm
http://www.codersrevolution.com/index.cfm/2008/7/13/Just-when-you-felt-safe-SQL-Injection-and-MySQL

Comment: I am not sure if this works exactly as in python i have now as a test case: "UPDATE stone set results = 'None2' where results='None';" This does however not change the variable value...

Comment: I wasn't sure if when you said None you meant null? If you intended None to mean null you can use something like this (MYSQL):

sql = "UPDATE stone set results=\'None\' where results is null" cursor = conn.Execute($sql) rows = cursor.Affected_Rows()

Comment: What I have done now is the following, I changed NULL to None but when I do a select statement for a variable that changed from NULL to None contains no quotes thus None is not like 'None' and thus cannot be found when SELECT * FROM stone WHERE results = 'None' ... And results = None can't work as SQL does not allow that. I even tried to change None into something else via... "UPDATE stone set results = 'None2' where results = 'None';" but it won't change anymore... odd...